# How to retrieve html file from a website and get data between specific tags using java

Tags: java, html

I am going to create a desktop client for my university's parent web interface. When logged in, a webpage displays the student details in a table. I want to retrieve those details using java.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Why not use web service instead of relying on html response? BTW, you can use RegExp here.

Comment: @Arvind why do you assume there's a web service?

Answer (score 1):

A short google search brought me to this library. https://jsoup.org

As it seems, it can send http requests (to receive the data from your university website) as well as parse these html to simple search for the tables you need.

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
log(doc.title());
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
  log("%s\n\t%s", 
    headline.attr("title"), headline.absUrl("href"));
}
```

If you don't know how html is structure you should take a short tutorial on how to write simple html to understand what is going on and what you are looking for.